# remove element from array based on sql query

Tags: php, arrays

`$_SESSION['lines']` is populated from a textbox that a user pastes into.  Before I do anything with the data, I want to run it through a filter to see if any of the values they've input are NOT in the database.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['lines'] as $q) {
$multiSupplierQuery      = "SELECT distinct supplier from allparts where quotePartNumber = '$q'";
$multiSupplierResult    = mysqli_query($con, $multiSupplierQuery);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($multiSupplierResult)) {
  $multiSupplier = $row['supplier'];
}
 if (!multiSupplier) {
  unset($_SESSION['lines'[]);
 }
}
```

The crux of this revolves around this statement:

```
 if (!multiSupplier) {
  unset($_SESSION['lines'[]);
}
```

What I'm trying to say is:  `each time we cycle through this, if multiSupplier doesn't exist, remove this particular element from the array.`

my `unset` syntax is wrong though... how do I make it right?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `[` at `unset($_SESSION['lines'[])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to add a `$` to your if statement. Change

```
if (!multiSupplier) {
```

to

```
if (!$multiSupplier) {
```

---

Also, to unset from the `$_SESSION` you need a key. Try changing

```
foreach ($_SESSION['lines'] as $q) {
```

to

```
foreach ($_SESSION['lines'] as $key=>$q) {
```

and then

```
unset($_SESSION['lines'][$key]);
```

Comment: Yup - I saw that typo too.  Thanks!  What's the difference between the answer that @Dagon provided above, `unset($_SESSION['lines'][$q]);` where no `key` is used and your answer?  After some testing, your solution worked while the one above did not.

Comment: When using the foreach, `$q` contains a copy of the item in the `$_SESSION` array; modifying `$q` doesn't change `$_SESSION` at all. Also, `$q` is not an array key, so it doesn't make sense to try to unset `$_SESSION['lines']`'s `$q` key. When you add the `$key`, it tells you where the actual data is stored in the `$_SESSION['lines']` variable so php knows which item to unset.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your unset usage, you just have an unnecessary opening square bracket.

```
unset($_SESSION['lines'[]);
```

should be

```
unset($_SESSION['lines']);
```

And you'll be good to go.

Comment: no - what this does is it completely unsets the entire 'lines' array that I've made, (e.g. - removes all data from it.)  I just want to remove THAT specific element from the entire array if the query comes back with no results....  So - if `$_SESSION['lines']` is comprised of 6 elements, and element 3 isn't in the database, I want to remove item 3 from the `$_SESSION['lines']` array, but keep items, 1, 2, 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: then you want `unset($_SESSION['lines'][$q]);`

Comment: perfect - that's exactly what I needed... the `[$q]` part.  Awesome, thank you!